# Add xml text structure to xml document

Tags: c++, xml, pugixml

I have a loaded `pugi::xml_document` with e.g. `<node></node>` and want to
add xml text structure to this pugi xml doc!

example for xml text structure: (stored in std::string)

```
<cmd name="Test"><tag>some text</tag></cmd>
```

Final xml doc should look like this:

```
<node><cmd name="Test"><tag>some text</tag></cmd></node>
```

What's the best way to do this in pugixml?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some function to load the doc (`<node></node>`):

```
bool Class::ReadXmlString(std::string xml)
{
    try
    {               
        pugi::xml_parse_result parseResult = m_xmlDoc->load(xml.c_str());    
        return parseResult;         
    }
    catch(std::exception &exp) 
    {       
        return false; 
    }
}
```

function to add e.g.: `<cmd name="Test"><tag>some text</tag></cmd>`

```
bool Class::AddFragment(std::string node, std::string xmlValue)
{
    try
    {
        //  temporary document to parse the data from a string
        pugi::xml_document doc;
        if (!doc.load_buffer(xmlValue.c_str(), xmlValue.length())) return false;

        // select node from class member pugi::xml_document
        pugi::xml_node xmlNode = m_xmlDoc->select_single_node(("//" + node).c_str()).node();

        for (pugi::xml_node child = doc.first_child(); child; child = child.next_sibling())
        {
            xmlNode.append_copy(child);
        }
    }
    catch(std::exception &exp)
    {       
        return false;
    }
}
```